# Django. Why not create date field in DB?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model:

```
class Users_data (models.Model):
    first_name_user = models.CharField(max_length=45, verbose_name="")
    e_mail = models.EmailField(max_length=45, verbose_name="")
    e_mail2 = models.EmailField(max_length=45, verbose_name="")
    password = models.CharField(max_length=45, verbose_name="")
    password2 = models.CharField(max_length=45, verbose_name="")
    bir_date = models.DateField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="", blank=True, null=True),

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'Users_data'
```

Why not create a column - `bir_date` but all the rest column are created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the trailing comma after the field definition, `bir_date` is treated as a [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences). See how the comma changes the type of the variable:

```
>>> s = "test"
>>> type(s)
<type 'str'>
>>> s = "test",
>>> type(s)
<type 'tuple'>
```

Remove the comma and Django will "pick up" the field:

```
bir_date = models.DateField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="", blank=True, null=True)
```